# Estimating daily volatility of unevenly/irregularly spaced time series data

Tags: volatility, interpolation

Say I have time-series data that is unevenly spaced, with anything between 4-50 hours of spacing in between. The data comes from a trading account history, which has captured the balance of the portfolio after each trade.

I'd like to calculate the annualised daily volatility of this account in order to compute a sensible Sharpe ratio. As such, I am assuming volatility does not vary with time.

I've read [How do you estimate the volatility of a sample when points are irregularly spaced?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/how-do-you-estimate-the-volatility-of-a-sample-when-points-are-irregularly-space) but do not have access to the knowledge, experience or computational power required to solve for the maximum in the formula proposed.

What would be a reasonably good way to approximate the daily volatility of this time series? I can think of a few solutions and would be interested to hear if you have comments on them or if you had other ideas.

- **Solution #1:** Pretend my data is, in fact, regularly spaced
- **Solution #2:** Cut all but the last data point of each day
- **Solution #3:** As #2 but fill any gaps with some short EMA estimate (perhaps making use of [Eckner, 2015](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/882e/93570eae184ae737bf0344cb50a2925e353d.pdf))
- **Solution #4:** Use a method akin to that oulined in pp.38 of [Eckner, 2014](http://eckner.com/papers/unevenly_spaced_time_series_analysis.pdf), (if I've understood it correctly) and approximating the vol to the ATR scaled by $ \sqrt{ \frac{ \pi }{ 8 \rho } } $

Comment: The realized variance $v=\sum_i (x_{i+1}-x_i)^2$ generalizes to $v=\sum_i (\frac{x_{i+1}-x_i}{t_{i+1}-t_i})^2$ when the time intervals are unequal, but deterministic. (Assuming a zero mean for simplicity).

Comment: @AlexC Indeed my intervals are deterministic as I am looking at historical returns. If I've understood you correctly: assuming zero mean (happy to do this, as this is already the convention I would use to calculate volatility normally), I can simply scale each return by the inverse of the time taken to realise that return, and then calculate the standard deviation (as per usual) on these scaled returns?

Comment: Yes. But let's first see if someone upvotes my comment...

Comment: @AlexC what do you mean by when the time intervals are "deterministic"? As in when they don't depend on the realisation of the underlying stock process? Also, shouldn't it be $v = \sum_i \frac{(x_{i+1}-x_i)^2}{t_{i+1} - t_i}$

Answer (score 1):

A simple estimate of the volatility $\sigma$ of an asset given $N$ samples of  asset prices $S_i$ at times $t_i$ is:

$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\log(S_i / S_{i-1})^2}{t_i - t_{i-1}}
$$

This is the maximum likelihood estimate of $\sigma$ when the asset price is assumed to be a Wiener process with no drift. In this case, the transition probability of observing $x_i=\log(S_i/S_{i-1})$ is given by:

$$
P(x_i) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi(t_i - t_{i-1})}} \exp({\frac{-{x_i}^2}{2 \sigma^2 (t_i-t_{i-1})}})
$$

The estimate maximizes $\prod_{i=1}^{N} P(x_i)$. It can be derived by differentiating the logarithm of this product with respect to $\sigma$ and setting this to zero.

A more complicated model may include drift (e.g. [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/2624/33381)), but maximizing the log likelihood may require an [optimization algorithm](https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/mathematical_optimization/#choosing-a-method) like BFGS if an analytical solution can't be found. In this case, giving the gradient and a good initial guess to the solver will massively speed up the solution time.

Comment: If I understand the first equation correctly, you're taking care of the uneven spacing by normalizing the returns with respect to time?

Comment: @Doggie52 Yes, but this form is rigorous as it follows from this transition probability model. There are plenty of other incorrect/unjustified guesses for how to normalize properly. Also for other readers, note the units for volatility are log-return per square root time, and also note this provides an intuitive single-sample estimate when N=1.

Comment: @JoseOrtiz3 could you kindly direct us to some relevant literature?